Have any devatas given boon to Brahmanas?
Since Brahmanas considered superior to Devas and Vishnu himself considers them worshipable..Is there any example in scripture where brahmanas have been given boons by devatas?
Any examples ot Brahmanas being granted boons by Vishnu or His Kshatriya avataras Rama and Krishna..

Lord Krishna granted a boon to Sage Utanka that whenever he feels thirsty, rain clouds will appear in the desert and provide him water -

I will make you successful and invincible through the water. O
brahmana ! Whenever you face a desire for water, clouds full of water
will appear in this desert. O descendant of the Bhrigu lineage! They
will give you tasty water. Those clouds will be known as Utanka clouds
and will become famous.” Thus addressed by Krishna, the brahmana was
delighted. O descendant of the Bharata lineage! Even today, Utanka
clouds shower down in the desert.


1889 ( 54), Ashvamedhika Parva, Mahabharata.

